# Rellenar salto de id AUTOINCREMENT

Tags: mysql, autoincremento

Tengo una duda, es posible rellenar el salto de id de un campo autoincrement.

Teniendo los id

```
1
2
3
```

un vacío y luego

```
105
106
107
```

Como puedo hacer para setear el AUTOINCREMENT EN `4` y cuando llegue a `104` salte a `108`

EL siguiente código ya lo intente 
`ALTER TABLE mitabla AUTO_INCREMENT=4`

Comment: entonces más que auto increment será manual increment, lo que me hace pensar que lo que buscas es otra cosa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mí en su momento me costó aceptarlo porque, en mayor o menor medida, todos tenemos ese TOC. Seré directo: `olvida ese problema porque no existe`.

Los autoincrementales están ahí para garantizar que no se repita ningún identificador, no para que sean correlativos ni mucho menos para rellenar huecos.

Si estás utilizando el autoincremental para etiquetar cajas, estanterías, cajones o carpetas, deja de usarlo y gestiona esa etiqueta desde otro campo sobre el que tengas más control.

Podrías tener la tentación de, al no borrar registros, reutilizarlos. Mala idea: un `INSERT` fallido te dejará igualmente el hueco.

Siento que la solución a tu problema sea ignorarlo, pero el mundo es como es y no como nos gustaría que fuera.

Para el caso que comentas, una posible solución sería que insertaras manualmente aquellos huecos que tengas constancia de que existen y no van a generar ninguna confusión del tipo registros borrados que vuelven a existir. Algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE etiquetas(
  id_etiqueta int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  etiqueta varchar(15)
  );

INSERT INTO etiquetas (etiqueta) VALUES
  ('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7');

DELETE FROM etiquetas WHERE id_etiqueta<5;

INSERT INTO etiquetas (id_etiqueta, etiqueta)
  VALUES (1,'1');
```

Ése último `INSERT` no afecta al `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Una forma de evitar situaciones de este tipo se plantea en la pregunta: [Trigger enumerar consecutivamente sin auto_increment](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/358849)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, en realidad el tema es el tamaño del campo autoincrement.

Salto de 500.000 a 6.000.000 y la brecha es gigante...

Comment: Siempre puedes hacer un `ALTER TABLE tabla CHANGE id id INT(15)` o vaciar las tablas y volver a rellenarlas... el id debería ser algo interno

Comment: Si el tamaño del campo no es un problema. El tema es el excesivo incremento. Por todo lo demás funciona todo bien.

Comment: Si es forzoso el cambio, entonces puedes manejarlo a nivel de algún lenguaje de programación, haciendo un select por ejemplo y verificando si el valor excede una cantidad determinada y en caso de serlo realizas un ALTER

Comment: Amplío la respuesta con una solución a ese salto tan grande que tienes en tu tabla, pero fíjate que no toco el `AUTO_INCREMENT` y me aseguro que los ID que reciclo no producirán ninguna confusión

Comment: Genial muchas gracias... no queria autoincrementar manualmente los registros pero creo que va a ser la única solución.

Comment: Yo no podría haberlo explicado mejor.

Comment: Edito la respuesta con referencia a una pregunta relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/358849