# Trigger enumerar consecutivamente sin auto_increment

Tags: trigger

Hola necesito enumerar las UF desde el 1 hasta el numero de UF que yo quiera con triggers sin utilizar el auto_increment, he intentado hacer lo que veis más abajo pero me da error y nose como continuar, os pido un poco de ayuda, ya que es un trabajo importante.

````
create database prog;
use prog;

drop table if exists uf;
drop table if exists modulo;

create table modulo (
 num int primary key,
 titulo varchar(100) not null,
 horas int not null
);

create table uf (
 modulo_num int not null,
 uf_num int not null,
 titulo varchar(100) not null,
 horas int not null,
 primary key (modulo_num, uf_num),
 foreign key (modulo_num) references modulo(num) 
);

insert into modulo values
(1,'Sistemas operativos',165),
(2,'Bases de datos',192); ```
--  MI INTENTO DE TRIGGER
delimiter $$
create trigger _incrementar before insert on uf for each row
begin
    declare _uf_num int;
    set _uf_num = _uf_num + 1;
    set _uf_num = (select count(_uf_num) + 1);
    insert into uf (uf_num) values
    (_uf_num);
end$$
````

Answer (score 0):

Me parece haber entendido algo así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER _incrementar BEFORE INSERT
  ON uf FOR EACH ROW
  set new.uf_num=(SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM uf);
```

De forma que, al realizar un INSERT, asigne al campo `uf_num` el valor correspondiente al número de registros preexistentes más uno.

Entiendo que no usas un autonumérico para que tu numeración sea correlativa sin que haya saltos, por ejemplo, por inserciones fallidas a consecuencia de infracciones de clave ajena. Está bien pensado para no caer en [Rellenar salto de id AUTOINCREMENT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/353629/rellenar-salto-de-id-autoincrement/353634#353634) aunque, ¿qué pasaría si eliminas algún `uf_num` intermedio? ¿No sería mejor algo así?

```
CREATE TRIGGER _incrementar BEFORE INSERT
  ON uf FOR EACH ROW
  set new.uf_num=(SELECT MAX(uf_num)+1 FROM uf);
```

Pensando, por ejemplo, en un etiquetado de cajones o números de expediente o factura.